# Disable auto-login on Lubuntu 18.10

Tags: lubuntu, auto-login

When I installed Lubuntu, I checked the auto-login option.  I'd like to turn it off now.  I'm not seeing it in the GUI settings anywhere, and I can't find a conf file for it (such as in /etc/sddm/).

Can someone tell me how to turn it off?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In LXQt**

Edit the file `/etc/sddm.conf`

`sudo nano /etc/sddm.conf`

Look for a section marked `[Autologin]`

It should appear as

```
[Autologin]
User=<Some username>
Session=<usually blank>
Relogin=False
```

Remove the username from the User key, and any session name from the Session key

Save the changes to the file, and reboot!

Source of information: `man sddm.conf`

**In Ubuntu using GDM**

Using a GUI, Click the settings icon -> Details -> Users -> User in question

Then uncheck the 'autologin' box

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not seeing that.  I have the LXQt desktop.  My users page looks like this:  https://lucency.co/ImageShare/?view=bnbwn2lqohb  I'm sorry if I'm not explaining or understanding something well.  I'm new to Ubuntu.

Comment: What is under the 'advanced' tab?

Comment: @Jared Updated the answer to account for LXQt / Sddm....

Comment: The Advanced tab has Login Shell and Home Directory paths.  Your answer did the trick, though.  Thank you so much!