# Ubuntu 20.04 as Hyper-V guest xrdp

Tags: 20.04, xrdp, hyper-v

How to optain IP for my ubuntu vm in the hyper-v console?

Because I have an unsolved issue to connect to linux hyper-v guest via [xrdp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/679075/xrdp-connection-denied-to-debian-guest-on-hyperv) I tried to reproduce the issue. So I [installed an ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1246362/how-to-setup-xrdp-for-ubuntu-20-04-in-windows-hyper-v) VM. The new VM uses same hyper-v network-adapter configuration. If I connect to the new VM via hyper-v console:

1. I have internet connection,
2. correct IP4 settings and
3. the xrdp daemon is running.

But in consequence if I connect via hyper-v console there are no greeting with a windows connection prompt that asks for a screen resolution. If I connect via `mstsc.exe` no session is created and no IP-Address appears in the hyper-v console:

[image]
[image]

Compare to my debian vm:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess

If you are not getting the screen resolution popup from the Hyper-v Console, it's probably because you have not enabled the enhanced mode for your VM.  You have to look at two places for Enhanced Mode

1. Hyper-V Settings >Enhanced Mode Policy > Tick the box to allow it
2. When you connect to the VM (via the Hyper-v console), on the menu, select View and   ensure that  Enhanced mode is selected.  If it's greyd out, it probably because the hyper-v settings is not set correctly

The fact that you cannot perform an RDP to the Ubuntu machine is because the script provided to enable enhanced mode does not enable VSOCK usage and TCP/IP Usage

As a final word, we have written about xrdp and Enhanced mode and offered a possible approach to use both method.  You can always check [this post](https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=17109) on our blog and see if this could be useful for you

Hope this help

Till next time